# Creating a REST interface for BotBuilder bot without registering it

Tags: node.js, rest, botframework

I'm trying to use the Node.js implementation of Microsoft BotBuilder.

With the ConsoleConnector, I'm able to interact with my bot via the command-line. I do not have to register my bot, and I do not have to use the framework emulator. This is all I have to do:

```
var builder = require('botbuilder');                       

var connector = new builder.ConsoleConnector().listen();          
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session) {
    session.send("You said: %s", session.message.text);           
});
```

However, instead of the command-line, **I'd like to use a REST interface. Is there any way I can do this, without having to register my bot or run the framework emulator?**

(I notice there's no RestConnector, but something like that would be really useful!)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope to clarify a little. BotFramework emulator is a client that run locally and you can avoid the registration of your bot. You may use [restify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/restify) to expose the botconnector to REST interfaces.

For example:

```
var builder = require('botbuilder');
var restify = require('restify');

// Setup Restify Server
var server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
    console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url);
});

// Create chat bot
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
    appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
});

var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, [
    function (session) {
        ...
    }
]);

//Listen to /api/messages
server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Do you have any examples of initiating a conversation via REST? (eg, using Curl or any other mechanism). Their API docs are a little hard to follow: https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/connector/